# Determining Vaadin screen space available and GridLayout

Tags: java, awt, vaadin, layout-manager, grid-layout

I'm trying to create a Vaadin application that has a grid inside a `VerticalLayout` which takes up most of the screen (so, small header, big grid, small footer). Easy enough to do.

But I want to calculate the size of the browser area available to me and divide that up into 80x60 pixel blocks, so different displays would have a different number of `GridLayout` cells. i.e. the larger your display the more cells you have in your grid.

The problem I'm having is that at the `init()` time, the `WebBrowser` information that I can get the width and height from, isn't available to me (and it says so in the API). I've tried the example code but 'attach' is still being called from `init`, effectively.

I could use some sort of listener (not sure which) to do my grid setup and adding controls to all that but that sounds really messy and cumbersome to me.

So, the questions:

1. What Listener would be appropriate?
2. Isn't there just a simple way of working out what available screen space there is?

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative 1**:

```
WebBrowser browser = ((WebApplicationContext) getApplication().getContext()).getBrowser();
int width = browser.getScreenWidth();
int height = browser.getScreenHeight();
```

**Best Way:**

```
getApplication().getMainWindow().addListener(new ResizeListener() {
    @Override
    public void windowResized(ResizeEvent e) {
        System.out.printf("window info : %sx%s\n", 
                         e.getWindow().getWidth(), 
                         e.getWindow().getHeight()));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but is it always guaranteed that you get a resize event when the application starts (regardless of whether the browser window is resized) - or does it depend on what browser your using?

Comment: That's a good question. Probably you will have to use both alternatives in different parts of your code.

Comment: btw, how will you handle this problem when (width % 80 != 0 || height % 60 != 0) ?

Comment: If I understood your question right... you set the size of the grid to the multiple of the number of cells you can fit in it and centre that within the display (you will undoubtedly get a little 'left over' around the edges of the grid). That way you get a nicely standard grid space - that's the theory anyway, I'm not having much luck with Vaadin.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `Application` implement `HttpServletRequestListener`, and implement the callback like so:

```
public void onRequestEnd(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    WebBrowser browser = ((WebApplicationContext) getContext()).getBrowser();
    int width = browser.getScreenWidth();
    int height = browser.getScreenHeight();
    if(width==0 || width==-1) return;
    if(height==0 || height==-1) return;
    System.out.println("Your browser window is "+width+" by "+height);
```

Comment: Actually this only works for setting the size of components after I hit refresh on the browser. Just need to figure out how to refresh the client now.